# Why is grass looking tilted?

Tags: particles, hair

I was trying to follow CGMatter's tutorial of how to make realistic grass (Create Grass Fast Blender Tutorial). So far so good, but now it looks like there is a wind blowing all of the grass to one side. Is there any way to fix this or do I have too many subdivisions? If you have any suggestions, please let me know.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the mesh used as particles/hairs and go into edit mode.
Rotate and move the object (in edit mode) till the emitter emits the mesh correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem :)